# How to use ".." to pass URL parameters into Jersey?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I've encountered this URL RESTful query:

http://rest.ensembl.org/map/cdna/ENST00000288602/100..300?content-type=application/json

Where 100..300 are parameters that says: "from 100 to 300" (indexes). I can change those parameters as i'd like.

I want to have this kind of query parameter passing in my web-service as well. How can I annotate this in a Jersey API, and how do I get the parameter values?

Comment: why not just pass paramter as 100-300 then parse the request like string.split("-").  Then convert min 100 and max 300 to ints and create an array of elements from 100 to 300.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Path annotation to map the 100..300 kind of URL.

For example, the below code works fine for me.

```
@Path("/Test")
@Component
public class TestRestfulService {
        @GET
        @Path("/100..200")
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public String getText(){
            return "Success";
        }
}
```

Using the above code you can access the method by localhost:8080/test/100..200.

Hope this solves the problem!